# Having trouble with iterating over dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined a class Lexicon:

```
class Lexicon:
    """stores known word stems of various part-of-speech categories"""

    def __init__ (self):
        self.catDict = {}

    def add(self,stem,cat):
        for k, v in self.catDict.iteritems():
            if (k != cat and v != stem):
                self.catDict[cat] = stem
```

When I execute the `Lexicon.add()` method I want it to take a word e.g. "John" and the category of that word e.g. "P" so it could look something like this:

```
Lexicon.add("John","P")
```

I want this to be stored in the `catDict` dictionary. But only if there doesn't already exist a `'P':'John'` in the dictionary, my problem seems to be occurring with the `for` loop and `if` statement.

When testing without the `for` loop and `if` statement my code works. But when I have the `for` loop and `if` statement in my code to filter out any duplicate entries it leaves me with an empty dictionary. Here is the terminal transcript when I test it with the `for` loop and `if` statement present:

```
>>> from statements import Lexicon
>>> lx = Lexicon()
>>> lx.catDict
{}
>>> lx.add("John","P")
>>> lx.catDict
{}
>>>
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you only add the entry if its already there. it won't fill up.

Comment: Sort of like the cart before the horse, calling `iteritems` but there are never any items.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there's already a key `"P"` with some other value? Do you want to replace it, or ignore the new value? Or do you want the value to be a list of names?

Comment: Why even check? `self.catDict[cat] = stem` always replaces but that is harmless.... if stem is a string anyway.

Comment: I still don't have a good understanding of the rules. if I `add("John","P")` then `add("John","Q")` and then `add("Jane","P")`... what will be in the dict when I'm done.

Comment: @willrobertshaw... you asked the question and then went dark. Why ask if you are just going to walk away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is loop over every entry in the dictionary (keep in mind that initially it is empty, so nothing will happen), then for *each* entry if the key or value doesn't match your input, you store stem in `self.catDict[cat]`. Do you see the problem?

In fact there are two problems:
1. Since the dictionary is initially empty, the for loop is essentially a no-op the first time, so the dictionary stays empty, and the add method does nothing.
2. Even if you have something in the dictionary, you do the comparision on every iteration, so basically what you are doing is adding the entry as long as there is at least one entry in the dictionary that isn't the same as the entry you are adding.

However, your condition that it is added "only if there doesn't exist a `'P':'John'` in the dictionary is already provided by the dict class. A dict only ever has one entry with a given key, so if you execute `self.catDict['P'] = 'John'` and `'P':'John'` is already in the dictionary, you will still only have one `'P':'John'` in the dictionary.

EDIT:

My guess is that what you really want is a way to keep track of a dictionary with categories as keys and sets of stems as values. For this, a combination of `defaultdict` and `set` is perfect:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Lexicon:
    """stores known word stems of various part-of-speech categories"""

    def __init__ (self):
        self.catDict = defaultdict(set)

    def add(self,stem,cat):
        self.catDict[cat].add(stem)
```

The way this works is catDict is a defaultdict which is a dictionary that will call the function passed to it to construct a new value if an attempt is made to access a key that has not previously been set. In the add method we retrieve the value for a category with `sefl.catDict[cat]` if we have already stored something for that category, the previous set will be returned, if not a new set will be created and automatically set to `self.catDict[cat]`. Then we add the stem to that set. Because sets only contain distinct values, stem will only actually be added to the set if it is not already contained in the set.

Comment: And you are sure that is what OP wants? My comments cover those cases and I'm waiting to see what OP thinks of them.

Answer (score 1):

Normally dictionaries only have one way of looking up items, what you are doing would be more suitable for a tuple.

But since i don't know exactly what you are trying to do here is one possible solution:

```
def add(self,stem,cat):        
    """ Only adds stem if cat is not present. """        
    if not cat in self.catDict: # the proper way to look up an item in a dict
        self.catDict[cat] = stem
```

Comment: I think you've jumped the gun with this answer. There is an open question to OP about whether adds should be blocked if the same key but a different value is attempted.

Comment: @tdelaney If a key is present this means that a value is present. Thus any other add is irrelevant as if it is equal, the value is already there, if it is different we don't want to overwrite the current one.

Comment: _if it is different we don't want to overwrite the current one_ ... that's what we are trying to get clarified by OP. Right now he says not to replace if key _and_ value are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing for the key in the dict?

```
if some_key not in self.catDict.keys()
    self.catDict[somekey] = someValue
```